# How to go from a step function to a slope?

Tags: math, algebra, derivative

Currently, my program takes in an input and determines the output as a step function (if x >= 30, y = 100, else y=0). Another version has y=x at all times. Through both functions, y can only go from 0 to 100. 
I would like to have a third parameter that takes the function slowly from one to another.

One option was to just give it a weight (y=F1*alpha + F2 (1-alpha) such that alpha goes from 0 to 1 over time). However this leads to a discontinuous function which I am trying to avoid.

My ideal solution would look like a logistic function curve, but the end points have to be within  0 and 100. The step is also changing and can be anything between 0 and 100.

So is there any such function that may enable me to transition from a step function slowly to a y=x slope?

Edit: Added image [showing the two plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yECoh.png): the step function (F1) in black and the y=x slope (F2) in blue.

Comment: Itd be really helpful if you could draw graphs of your examples th help us visualize it

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a mathematics / numerical analysis question, not a computer programming question. There are various ways of approximating a step function with continuous functions. [One](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021904580900647), [two](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2923284/). [three](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/21659)